# Trouble with URL parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, url-parameters

I am working on a search form that I would like to post the searched by values in the url.  I am having trouble getting the url to include the parameters however.  They will post if I key in values in the view( if instead of $this->search_zip I key '12345').  Currently the search works as desired except for the url. I am currently getting the search terms from the form, would I need to change my controller setup to get them from the url instead?  If this is the case how would I filter?

Ultimately I would like my url to read:

*results/12345/otherparam*

I am currently getting

*results*

No matter what variables I key into the form.

**Module Config**

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'constraints' => array(
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true, //START OF CHILD ROUTES
                'child_routes' => array(
                'results' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'results[/:search_zip][/:search_industry]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'results',
```

**Results view**

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(
 'home/results',
 array(
     'action' => 'results',
     'search_zip'=> $this->search_zip,
     'search_industry' => 'industry_name'

    echo $this->formRow($form->get('industry_name'));//this is the form field
    echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
```

**Controller**

```
 //beginning of the results action
    $request = $this->getRequest();   
             $form = new SearchForm($dbAdapter);  
             if ($request->isPost()) {
                 $search = new MainSearch();          
                 $form->setInputFilter($search->getInputFilter());                
                 $form->setData($request->getPost());  
                 if ($form->isValid()) {
```

At the end of my resultsAction I return the form and the results (per the album example)

```
     return array(
        'form' => $form,
        'pros' => $fetchPros,
              );
```

Thank you,
M

Comment: `'search_zip'=> '$this->search_zip',` should be `'search_zip'=> $this->search_zip,` if that's not the only issue, please could you edit your question to make the issue clearer: what are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: I have updated my question.  That did not fix it.  I was in there messing around and forgot to update before posting.  thanks.

Comment: Could you show us more of the routes array?

Comment: There's not enough code in the example to show how you're transferring the vars from the request to the form. That said, I suggest you consider query params, rather than route params for this use case.

Comment: I have added more detail.  Zend now recommends route params as opposed to query params http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2013-01

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will give you an array containing your desired parameters
$params = $this->params()->fromRoute();
//Then you can simply use them like this
$search_zip = $params['search_zip'];
$search_industry  = $params['search_industry'];
```